lintrunner: ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pkg_resources.extern'
Trying to install lintrunner with pip in a RISCV:
$ pip install lintrunner
Collecting lintrunner
  Using cached lintrunner-0.12.5.tar.gz (62 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[...]
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-im5_kq1b/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
          from pkg_resources.extern import appdirs
      ImportError: cannot import name 'appdirs' from 'pkg_resources.extern' (/tmp/pip-build-env-im5_kq1b/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py)

pkg_resources is provided by setuptools, and setuptools and appdirs packages are installed in my virtual env:
$ pip list
Package      Version
------------ -------
appdirs      1.4.4
pip          24.0
platformdirs 4.3.6
setuptools   69.5.1

Just in case, I also installed the system-wide package provided through repos:
$ apt search appdirs
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python3-appdirs/noble,now 1.4.4-4 all [installed]

Running python 3.12.3 in Ubuntu 24-04.1 architecture RISCV64.
Similar answered question here on stackoverflow from 2015: ImportError: No module named 'appdirs'
does not work in my environment probably to RISCV64 architecture or new conflict between packages that are not present in the linked question (since answers are about reinstalling appdirs).
Also, notice that appdirs is currently deprecated in favor of platformdirs (https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs/commit/8734277956c1df3b85385e6b308e954910533884)

This question is similar to: ImportError: No module named 'appdirs'. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

try this py -m pip install appdirs

It's different since that post is using old Ubuntu distro for standard x86 Linux.
Solutions from there are not working: as you can see in my post, appdirs is already installed in the virtual environment (version 1.4.4) and system-wide through apt (version 1.4.4 as well).
